# daysApart counting numbers twice

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that finds the number of days between two dates. I have no idea what's causing the error, but the pattern looks like it's adding the number of days between the first date in the year and the second date in the same year. That was a bad explanation, but please look at the daysApart method (last method before main). 
Here's a printout of the error it runs into: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZTsP.png

```
public class PA05{


    public static boolean isLeapYear(int y){
        if ((y%4 ==0) && (y%100 != 0)){
            return true;
        } else if ((y%4==0) && (y%100==0) && (y%400 == 0)) {
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }

        public static int daysInMonth(int month, int year){
            if (month == 1){
                return 31;
            }
            if((month == 2) && (isLeapYear(year)== true)){
                return 29;
            } else if ((month == 2) && (isLeapYear(year) == false)){
                return 28;
            } else if (month ==3){
                return 31;
            } else if (month == 4){
                return 30;
            } else if (month == 5){
                return 31;
            } else if (month == 6){
                return 30;
            } else if (month == 7){
                return 31;
            } else if (month == 8){
                return 31;
            } else if (month == 9){
                return 30;
            } else if (month == 10){
                return 31;
            } else if (month == 11){
                return 30;
            } else if (month == 12){
                return 31;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        public static int daysInMonth(int month, boolean isLeap){
            if (month == 1){
                return 31;
            } else if((month == 2) && (isLeap== true)){
                return 29;
            } else if ((month == 2) && (isLeap == false)){
                return 28;
            } else if (month ==3){
                return 31;
            } else if (month == 4){
                return 30;
            } else if (month == 5){
                return 31;
            } else if (month == 6){
                return 30;
            } else if (month == 7){
                return 31;
            } else if (month == 8){
                return 31;
            } else if (month == 9){
                return 30;
            } else if (month == 10){
                return 31;
            } else if (month == 11){
                return 30;
            } else if (month == 12){
                return 31;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        public static boolean isValid(int month, int day, int year){
            if (year<= 0){
                return false;
            } else if(month>12){
                return false;
            } else if (month == 1 && day > 31){
                return false;
            } else if ((month == 2) && (isLeapYear(year)==true) && (day>29)){
                return false;
            } else if ((month == 2) && (isLeapYear(year)==false) && (day>28)){
                return false;
            } else if (month == 3 && day > 31){
                return false;
            } else if (month == 4 && day > 30){
                return false;
            } else if (month == 5 && day > 31){
                return false;
            } else if (month == 6 && day > 30){
                return false;
            } else if (month == 7 && day > 31){
                return false;
            } else if (month == 8 && day > 31){
                return false;
            } else if (month == 9 && day > 30){
                return false;
            } else if (month == 10 && day > 31){
                return false;
            } else if (month == 11 && day > 30){
                return false;
            } else if (month == 12 && day > 31){
                return false;
            } else{
                return true;
            }
        }

        public static int daysInYear(int year){
            if(isLeapYear(year)==true){
                return 366;
            } else {
                return 365;
            }
        }
        public static int dayOfYear(int month, int day, int year){
            int days = day;
            if (isLeapYear(year)==true){
                for(int i = 1; i<month; i++){
                    days += daysInMonth(i, true);
                }
            } else {
                for(int i = 1; i<month; i++){
                    days += daysInMonth(i, false);
                }
            }
            return days;
        }

        public static int daysToEndOfYear(int month, int day, int year){
            int daysLeft = 0;
            if (isLeapYear(year)==true){
                for(int i = month+1; i<=12; i++){
                    daysLeft += daysInMonth(i, true);
                }
                daysLeft += daysInMonth(month, true)-day;
            } else {
                for(int i = month+1; i<=12; i++){
                    daysLeft += daysInMonth(i, false);
                }
                daysLeft += daysInMonth(month, false)-day;
            }return daysLeft;
        }

        public static boolean isBefore(int m1,int d1,int y1,int m2,int d2,int y2){
            if(y2>y1){
                return true;
            } else if (y2==y1){
                if (m2>m1){
                    return true;
                } else if (m2<m1){
                    return false;
                } else {
                    if (d2>d1){
                        return true;
                    } else if (d2<d1){
                        return false;
                    } else{
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static int daysApart(int m1,int d1, int y1,int m2,int d2, int y2){
            if(isValid(m1,d1,y1) && isValid(m2,d2,y2)){
                int days = 0;
                if (y1<y2){
                    days += Math.abs(dayOfYear(m1,d1,y1)-dayOfYear(m2,d2,y2));
                    System.out.println(days);
                    for (int j = y1; j<y2; j++){
                        System.out.println(days);
                        days += daysInYear(j);

                    }   
                } else if (y2<y1){
                    days+= -Math.abs(dayOfYear(m1,d1,y1)-dayOfYear(m2,d2,y2));
                    System.out.println(days);
                    for (int j = y2; j<y1; j++){
                        System.out.println(days);
                        days += daysInYear(j);
                    }           
                } else{
                    days += Math.abs(dayOfYear(m1,d1,y1)-dayOfYear(m2,d2,y2));
                }
                return Math.abs(days);

            } else{
                return -1;
            }

        }
        public static void main(String[] args){
            // System.out.println(isLeapYear(2012));
            // System.out.println(daysInMonth(2,2012));
            // System.out.println(daysInMonth(2,true));
            // System.out.println(isValid(2,29,3));
            // System.out.println(isValid(2,29,2004));
            // System.out.println(isValid(13,13,2000));
            // System.out.println(daysInYear(2012));
            // System.out.println(dayOfYear(12,30,2014));
            // System.out.println(daysToEndOfYear(12,30,2014));
            // System.out.println(isBefore(5,20,1955,5,25,1955));
            // System.out.println(daysApart(1,1,2014,1,20,2014));
            // System.out.println(daysApart(1,20,2014,1,1,2014));
            // System.out.println(daysApart(1,1,1897,1,1,1898));
            System.out.println(daysApart(11,15,2004,1,15,2012));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is not homework, go read up on [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) objects.  Actually, you should probably do that anyway.

Here's the error:

```
 days += Math.abs(dayOfYear(m1,d1,y1)-dayOfYear(m2,d2,y2));
```

You should not be using `Math.abs`.  You also should change the `+=` to `-=`.  You make the same mistake in the other branch.

Comment: I'm still getting the wrong answer. My code looks like this:
    days-= (dayOfYear(m1,d1,y1)-dayOfYear(m2,d2,y2));

These are the logic errors I'm getting: [link](http://i.imgur.com/i2bjmgC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are having incorrect days apart when second date has month and day occurring before your first date's month and day i.e. **Nov 15** 2004 and **Jan 15** 2012, and **Sep 25** 1932 and **Jun 21** 1993

on your first if condition, Just change. Then check the second condition if changes are also needed.

> days += Math.abs(dayOfYear(m1,d1,y1)-dayOfYear(m2,d2,y2));

to

> days += (dayOfYear(m2, d2, y2) - dayOfYear(m1, d1, y1))